# Recuperar un proyecto Angular luego del ng build

Tags: angular

Debido a que la empresa donde trabajo sufrió un ciber-ataque, perdí mis proyectos de API-REST con angular y laravel, ya que los códigos fuentes fueron dañados también, de más esta decir que no había creado un repositorio, como github, (de ahora en más lo haré siempre). Pero la aplicación está corriendo, ya que el servidor no se dañó,por lo tanto el  back-end está disponible en su totalidad, pero del front solo quedó la carpeta de distribución.

**Pregunta**.

¿Existe alguna posibilidad de recuperar los códigos a partir de la compresión?
Encontré una forma, un poco rudimentaria para resolver parte del problema, voy viendo en la consola del navegador, y en console.log() muestra el componente que la imprime, y tengo acceso al código fuente de cada uno, pero, reconstruirlo de esa forma será engorroso, además que no tengo acceso a los services o a los models, por ejemplo.

Cualquier información, es valorada.
Un abrazo a todos y a cada uno.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132809/para-que-sirven-los-archivos-js-map/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si la aplicación fue compilada en modo producción (`ng build --prod`) no debería ser posible recuperar las fuentes de forma fácil sin descompilar el código Javascript generado.

Si fue compilada en modo debugger, como parece ser el caso, el código TypeScript está allí y debería ser recuperable desde la consola del navegador, con la tecla F12, sección "Sources", aparecerá un `webpack://` y allí debería estar la fuente TypeScript original.

Pero como reitero, esto solo si el código fue compilado en modo depuración (`ng build`). Si no, solo tienes la fuente JavaScript y esa está compilada y optimizada y no es sencilla de descompilar.

Comment: Gracias Marc. Mirá yo siempre compilo como ng build, jamás uso el --prdo. estaría en el caso de la posible recuperación? Gracias.

Comment: Marc, acabo de revisar,  y sí... están allí donde dices. Muchísimas gracias, no sabes de la que me salvaste. Un abrazo Grande!!!

Comment: Precisamente por que un tercero podría recuperar el código fuente de tu aplicación, es recomendable que cuando lances a producción compiles con el ``--prod``, para evitar que nadie que use tu aplicación pueda ver su código fuente de forma sencilla. Sin embargo, en este caso, esta "mala práctica" te ha salvado la vida.

Comment: Jaja, tal cual. De todos modos estos sistemas son de uso interno, pero viene bien el consejo.

Answer (score 2):

Si la compilación para producción no incluye los ficheros `.map` ,me temo que vas a tardar menos rehaciéndola que intentando obtenerla. Lo que hay en `dist` es la versión *minificada* de la compilación:

- El compilador transforma el código Typescript a Javascript, pero para que la inyección de código funcione, ha de "preprocesar" las anotaciones (`@Input`,`@Component`...).
- Además, une para cada componente el código con la plantilla... que también se transforma en Javascript. Del mismo modo, los estilos se añaden en Javascript, no hay ficheros CSS fuera de las librerías que hayas importado (Bootstrap, Material, Font Awesome o similares).
- Tras todas las tranformaciones, se minifica, quedando ilegible.

Comment: Pablo. Muchas gracias por tu explicación, es bueno saber exactamente lo que hace. Por suerte, como dijo Marc en el comentario, voy a poder recuperarlos, Gracias a Dios. Pero me viene bien tu explicacion. Un abrazo.